# Generating sequences a recursively defined math string in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a sequence defined:

[image]

and my current code:

```
a = [1]
i=1
while a[-1] < 50:
    if a[-1] + 5*i < 50:
        a.append(a[-1] + 5*i)
        i+=1
    else:
        break
```

Output:

```
[1, 6, 16, 31]
```

can it be done more elegantly and optimally?

Comment: Yes. You should ask this question at [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com) to learn how.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One liners using [accumulate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.accumulate)

**Solution 1: Creates n Terms**

```
from itertools import accumulate

def seq(n):
  " Creates n terms of sequence"
  return list(accumulate(range(1, n+1), lambda acc, v: acc + 5*(v-1)))

print(seq(5))     # Generate first 5 terms
# Out: [1, 6, 16, 31, 51]
```

**Solution 2--Creates up to Max Value**

```
from itertools import accumulate, takewhile, count

def seq_gen(MAX):
  " terms up to value MAX "
  return list(takewhile(lambda v: v<=MAX, accumulate(count(start=1), lambda acc, v: acc + 5*(v-1))))

print(seq_gen(50))  # Generate to a maximum value of 50
# Out: [1, 6, 16, 31]
```

Comment: @ggorlen--good point.  Added a second solution that handles this case but still based upon accumulate.

Comment: Looks great--thanks! I forgot about `itertools.count`.

Answer (score 3):

I'd write it with a [generator](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/generator):

```
import itertools

def gen_sequence(maximum):
    n = 1

    for i in itertools.count(0):
        n = n + 5 * i

        if n > maximum: break

        yield n

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(list(gen_sequence(50))) # => [1, 6, 16, 31]
```

Or if you don't want to provide an upper limit, you can generate infinitely and let the caller dynamically decide when to quit. This enables the caller to step forward a few iterations and resume later or use [`itertools.takewhile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.takewhile) to immediately pick up to a limit:

```
from itertools import count, takewhile

def gen_sequence():
    n = 1

    for i in count(0):
        n = n + 5 * i
        yield n

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(list(takewhile(lambda x: x < 50, gen_sequence()))) # => [1, 6, 16, 31]
```

Whichever way you do it, it's a good idea to put the logic in a function with parameters and check the termination condition once. Ideally come up with a better name for the sequence than `gen_sequence`, which is rather ambiguous.

Answer (score 2):

This code is just like yours without useless if and break

```
a = [1]
i=1
while a[-1] + 5*i < 50:
    a.append(a[-1] + 5*i)
    i+=1
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's the way that I would write it:

```
def seq(a, n, lst=[]):
    a = a + 5 * (n - 1)
    n += 1
    if a < 50:
        lst.append(a)
        seq(a, n)
    return lst


print(list(seq(1, 1)))
```

Answer (score 0):

A really cute one liner:

```
def seq(n):
     return([(1+sum(i for i in range(0,5*j,5))) for j in range(1,n+1)])

print(seq(5))
[1, 6, 16, 31, 51]
```

Answer (score -1):

I didn't quite understand what exactly the function you are looking for returns,
but here's a general implementation in case you are looking to get the number An

```
def func(n):
    if n==1:
         return 1
    return (func(n-1) + 5*(n-1))
```

Comment: I don't think that's what OP is looking for. They specifically asked for a "elegant & optimal" solution

Comment: how can you implement this at a better run time than O(n)?

Comment: I don't know. But recursion is definitely not the answer :)